# How to remove a string inside greater/lesser than symbols < > using regex?

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I'm new to regex in general. What is the best way to remove a string inside of < >.`<string>body<string>`

Comment: @kirikaz add an example, please.

Comment: var input = "Text<removetext>";
  var output = Regex.Replace(input, @" ?\<.*?\>", string.Empty);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

`<[^>]+>`

- `<` - Matches `<`
- `[^>]+` - Match anything except `>`. one or more time.
- `>` - Matches `>`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/RRFw3s/1/)